# Can't connect to JDBC database

Tags: java, jpa, websphere, ibm-rad

I am trying to run a project in my WAS local server. The problem is I keep getting this error:

> Unsupported use of GenericConnection. A GenericConnection is provided
>   during application start when creating an EntityManagerFactory for a
>   persistence unit which has configured one of its datasource to be in
>   the component naming context; java:comp/env. During application start,
>   the component naming context will not exist, and the correct
>   datasource cannot be determined. When the persistence unit is used,
>   the proper datasource and connection will be obtained and used.

In my `persistence.xml` file I have this:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPUnit"    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL" > 
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/myPUnit</non-jta-data-source>  
    <properties>    
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="INFO" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>       
    </properties>   
</persistence-unit>
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with my `persistence.xml` file, but I keep getting the above mentioned error.

I'm using java 1.8, RAD 9.5 and WAS 8.5.

Comment: Is this Liberty or Traditional WebSphere? It seems that you have not configured a data source for "jdbc/myPUnit". If this is Liberty, make sure you have properly added a dataSource to your server.xml (You can find instructions here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_dep_configuring_ds.html). For Traditional WAS, try the following: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twim_fedmap_datasconf.html

Comment: @WillDazey It's traditional WAS and I have configured the data source for `jdbc/myPUnit` , so I don't understand what else might be wrong.